# selenium webdriver with python login issue with __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: python, selenium, csrf

login form has __RequestVerificationToken and my login python script with selenium doesn't work. I'm not sure what I need to do next.

When I run without the code to click on the Login button, I am able to see that the user and pwd are being filled in. When I run with the click, I see the user and pwd inputs being filled and then cleared, and nothing happens. 
I am also sure that the find_element_by_link_text is locating the "Login" text.
And , when I manually type the login and press "Login" it works.
This script works on other sites

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_driver_path = "C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
wd = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=options)
main_page_url = 'https://www.idocmarket.com/Security/Register'

def login():
    wd.get(main_page_url)
    wd.find_element_by_id('Login_Username').send_keys("user@someemail.com")  # login
    wd.find_element_by_id('Login_Password').send_keys("uniquepassword1")  # password
    wd.find_element_by_link_text('Login').click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initial login
    login()
```

I would expect a successful login and be presented with the next page

Comment: Provide URL, so we can to look/test. It can be antibot/captcha protected or smth like that.

Comment: it's possible the cookie isn't being stored.  What driver and options are you using?  (Show driver initialization...)  The anti-forgery token is tied to a session/cookie.

Comment: added the url and the additional code